# Android MediaCodec onOutputBufferAvailable - how to control callback frequency?

Tags: android-mediacodec, amr

I'm using [`MediaCodec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) with `targetSdkVersion 28` (Android 9) to convert the PCM stream from [`AudioRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) into AMR for a 3GPP/GSM VoIP application.  The [`onInputBufferAvailable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.Callback#onInputBufferAvailable(android.media.MediaCodec,%20int)) callback calls [`AudioRecord.read(bb, bb.limit())`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20int)) to queue the PCM samples to the encoder through the available [`ByteBuffer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer) and the [`onOutbufferAvailable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.Callback#onOutputBufferAvailable(android.media.MediaCodec,%20int,%20android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo)) callback accepts the AMR frame and passes it down to the RTP layer for packetization and transmission.  This works well on a variety of Android 7, 8 and 9 devices that we've been testing with.

However, on a Samsung XCoverPro running Android 10, the `onOutbufferAvailable()` callback isn't being triggered until 26 AMR frames are available, instead of a single frame as has happened previously.  Given that each frame represents 20ms of audio, this is causing an audio delay of over half a second.  So my question is, what control do I have over a `MediaCodec` audio encoder to get it to trigger the `onOutputBufferAvailable()` callback when a particular number of frames (ideally between 1 and 5) are available?

The encoder is created like this...

```
    String mimeType = MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_NB;
    MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
    format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, mimeType);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, sampleRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
    MediaCodec encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mimeType);
    encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
```

I've experimented with the [`MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat#KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE) parameter but that doesn't appear to have any effect, and setting [`MediaFormat.KEY_LATENCY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat#KEY_LATENCY) didn't help either (any anyway the docs say it only applies to video codecs).

Any suggestions?